# C Language: The datatype "double" is acting like the datatype "float"

Tags: c, printf, double, precision, conversion-specifier

I am learning the language C.
I am trying to print a set of numbers in the datatype "double" but it is only printing 7 digits like "float".

For example:

```
double temp = 23.3456789112345;

printf("%1f\n", temp);
```

Outputs this:

```
23.345679
```

However, once i changed where the decimal is like the following:

```
double temp = 2334567.89112345;

printf("%1f\n", temp);
```

It outputed this:

```
2334567.891123
```

SO it almost worked. Instead of outputing only 7 digits, it printed 13 digits. But I thought the datatype "double" could print 15-16 digits .

Comment: Six digits after the decimal point is "default". Review "format specifiers" doco for `printf()`. You can get more (or fewer) digits if you ask for them to be printed. (Experiment, and notice that the number will be correctly rounded, too.)

Comment: What is the point of `1` in `%1f` ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Possibly a typo meant to say`%lf`? Some dysfunctional fonts unsuitable for programming have the same symbol for `1` (one) and `l` (L).

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> **f,F** A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in the style [−]ddd.ddd, where the
> number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the
> precision specification. **If the precision is missing, it is taken as
> 6**; if the precision is zero and the # flag is not specified, no
> decimal-point character appears. If a decimal-point character appears,
> at least one digit appears before it. The value is rounded to the
> appropriate number of digits.

So for example you could write

```
double temp = 23.3456789112345;

printf("%.16f\n", temp);
```

Pay attention to that the length modifier `l` in `%lf` (I think you wanted to use `%lf` instead of `%1f`) is redundant and has no effect.